# Etymology of the term お局 and how it is used in slang

Tags: words, etymology

Can someone explain the etymology of the word お局 as well as how it is used in modern slang? I took an educated guess as to the colloquial meaning but am unsure of its nuances, be they comedic, insulting or otherwise....

> お局に小言を言われることにうんざりしている。
>
> I’m sick of being scolded by “otsubone.”
>
> 局: bureau; board; office; affair; conclusion; court lady; lady-in-waiting; her apartment;
>
> colloquial: an older single woman in a man's world/a term used to scornfully describe an unmarried veteran female employee [?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The etymology is prefix o + noun tubone (局). A tubone is a "room" in a large building. These rooms were primarly prepared for women who served at noble or imperial residences. The term has been around since around the 14th century.

Historically, an otubone was a woman who served at the imperial court and given a "room" (局) of her own. During the Edo period, the otubone was the one responsible for managing the women who served in the [大奥](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Coku).

In modern Japan, there is no longer an 大奥, and the meaning has changed to express a woman with some power who has been working for a long time. Until recently, women in Japan were expected to quit their jobs once they got married, so an otubone would be assumed to be single.

Comment: how is this term used colloquially? does it have either a negative or positive nuance?

Comment: As in your example, generally negatively. As I tried to indicate, an otubone has been working so long because she failed to marry. It is certainly nothing similar to a "career woman" that is found in western societies.